# Create new levels of a (date) factor, according to length of date variable

Tags: r, date, factors

I have a data frame (over 100,000 records with approx. 50 variables),  including a date variable which is stored as a factor. However, the length of this variable varies depending on the accuracy of the record keeping. It takes the length of 0, 4, 6, 8, 9 or 11. This is for:

`0: no date;`
`4: YYYY;`
`6: MMM-YY;`
`8: MMM-YYYY;`
`9: DD-MMM-YY;`
`11: DD-MMM-YYYY`

I'm attempting to get all the valid dates (length 4-9) into the same format as the dates of length 11 (the correct format). I've had serious problems creating a new factor variable. For example for date records of length 4, I will assume 01_Jul as the date for all years. I tried to expand the current set of date values:

`df$date <- ifelse(df$len==4, as.factor(paste0("01-Jul-", df$date)), df$date)`

but this results in a numeric value (not even character type). I then hope to use similar date imputations for lengths 6, 8 and 9. Does anybody have any advice on how to progress with these conversions?

My final intention is to convert the factor variable to a date variable, using the as.Date command.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you start with `df$date <- as.character(df$date)` and make all transformations with a vector of characters. Then, when you're done, convert back `df$date <- factor(df$date)`.

Comment: Thanks Rui, works nicely.